# How do I implement a money-based economy?

Tags: rogue-trader

Rogue Trader uses a "Profit Value" system, which treats wealth as another characteristic and to make a purchase you have to apply modifiers and make a percentile test against your PV. The point to this is that a Rogue Trader is usually so rich he doesn't need to count money.

In my campaign my Rogue Trader player is an extremely impoverished RT (he doesn't even have a Warrant of Trade yet, so it's fair to say that, ironically, he's not a Rogue Trader yet). Therefore, a Profit Value system doesn't make much sense at this point of the game.

I would like to use a money-based economy, that is, to give my players money for their achievements and they're free to spend it or save it. I would still use the "availability" tables, so they would or would not be able to find the item they're looking for, and then they would see if they have the money required to buy it.
The problem is that RT has no price list for its items. Do FFG other books use a system similar to what I'm looking for? If not, how could I put a price to each item?

Bear in mind the biggest problem I have is setting the rewards for their "quests", because I don't know how much is too much or too few.

Comment: You don't need to put 'Rogue Trader' at the beginning of your titles if the question is tagged with it. The tag is right there to indicate the system, and will appear alongside it virtually everywhere the site would display your question.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I see you edited some of my previous questions. You won't have to correct this kind of mistake anymore. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short Answer: Dark Heresy (DH) uses a money system, but it might not scale to Rogue Trader's (RT) level well.

Long Answer: The other FFG 40k books don't really have a focus on profit and the kind of scale in RT, so while DH certainly has money-based economy in terms of using "Thrones", it won't stretch to the kind of money being thrown around in RT's PV system.

If I recall, the PV system is for planet-wide sales and acquisitions, or for very long-term deals and treaties. DH might stretch to prices for a small planetbound vehicle, or a house - nowhere near RT's scale of food supplies for entire systems or terraforming rights to entire planets.

For comparison, Deathwatch works with Requisition for equipment, and Black Crusade (from my brief readthrough) uses Infamy (and Thrones in some cases?) - I haven't read enough of Only War to comment on the economy it uses. None of these would be what you need, though, as they are abstract like the PV system.

Comment: Even Dark Heresy stops using Thrones when you get to Ascension level characters. I've found that all of the WH40k rpgs are really abstract in their rules for acquiring resources.

Comment: Only War uses Requisition rolls - when you need new equipment, you send a request to the Departmento Munitorum, then hope they send you back what you asked for instead of a crate of Ogryn-sized dress uniforms and that it arrives before you get redeployed to the far side of the sector.